# Catch Boost exception

Tags: c++, boost, exception, boost-asio

When resolving a hostname with help of `icmp::resolver::query query(icmp::v4(), host, "");` and `destination = *resolver.resolve(query);` I get a exception when a hostname couldn't be resolved. Now I want to catch that exception, but it don't get caught. The code I have at the moment is:

```
        icmp::resolver::query query(icmp::v4(), host, "");  
        try
        {
            destination = *resolver.resolve(query);                                         
        }
        catch(boost::exception & e)
        {
             //Print exception
        } 
        catch (...) {
            //print exception   
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: The application is made in Visual Studio 2012 and have C++ unmanaged and managed(.net) code. The version of boost is 1.54.0

Comment: Does it catch at the `catch (...)` part?

Comment: No, it catch nothing at (..)

Comment: could it be crashing on the first line of code?

Comment: It crashes on destination = *resolver.resolve(query); Throw_exception.hpp get opened and then a arrow get on the following line `#ifndef BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE
    throw enable_current_exception(enable_error_info(e));`

Comment: @computergek92 catch boost::system::error_code instead of boost::exception.

Comment: Or try having a `catch(const std::exception& e)` one.

Comment: @ForEveR If that was the case, then `...` should have caught it

Comment: @Caesar yep, but... in this case - there is too little information, since query c-tor can't throws exception (in modern versions of boost at least), so we need to know, what version of boost op uses.

Comment: you could try the other overload that propagates an error code. See if that works.

Comment: `const std::exception& e` isn't also working. I have updated the question with some extra information about the application. My intention is catch an exception when an URL is typed, which not can be resolved. How can I make this possible? Some other way maybe?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the crash itself?  Does VS's exception assistant cause the debugger to enter into an execution break?  Alternatively, you could use the no-throwing overload for  [`resolver::resolve()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve/overload2.html).

Comment: @ForEveR You mean `boost::system::system_error`.

Comment: @TannerSansbury What do you mean by "Does VS's exception assistant cause the debugger to enter into an execution break?" I have now tried this: `icmp::resolver::query query(icmp::v4(), host, ""); destination = *resolver.resolve(query, ec); if (ec == null) {//print no error code} else {//print error code}` When executing the code with a host which is resolvable it works just fine. But when that isn't there will be the following exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. From the file named `vector`.

Comment: @computergek92: Sorry.  I was curious if the debugger is observing the exception.  Does the problem manifest itself in an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it without using a overloaded function of icmp::resolver function which gives an errorcode. Then I get a null pointer exception on the iterator and solved it to not have a pointer to the `resolver.resolve(query,ec)`

```
        {
            icmp::resolver::query query(icmp::v4(), host, "");
            iter = resolver.resolve(query, ec);
            if (!ec) 
            {
                destination = *iter;
            } 
            else 
            {
                ec.value();
            }
       }
```